# (Dis-)proving statements about sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have two statements about sets which are to be verified or falsified.

- $((a \in A) \wedge (B \subseteq A)) \Rightarrow a \in A \cup B$
- $(A\setminus B= \emptyset) \Rightarrow A = B$

For 1: The statement is wrong if $a \in A$ and $a \notin B$.

For 2: This statement is also false. 
It would be correct for $(\dots) \Rightarrow A \subseteq B$.

But how do I prove this mathematically correct ?

Thank you

Comment: It would help make your post easier to read by looking over [this page here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) and learning to type in MathJax and $\LaTeX$.

Answer (score 1):

For 1, the statement would have been false *if it instead read* $\Rightarrow a\in A\cap B$, but it doesn't read that way.  It reads $a\in A\cup B$.

Remember that unions are very much like the logical "*OR*."  $a\in A\cup B$ is the same as saying $a\in A$ or $a\in B$.

If $a\in A$ and (*whatever else, doesn't matter*), then in particular $a\in A$.  This implies that $a\in A$ or (*anything else, doesn't matter*).  So, statement one is in fact true.

To be more precise for a disproof for the second question, it is best to construct an explicit counterexample.  As you correctly note, the hypothesis would imply $A\subseteq B$.  Try to come up with a specific $A$ and a specific $B$ such that $A\subsetneq B$ (implying that $A\neq B$)

> For example, $A=\emptyset$ and $B=\{1\}$